# Powershell "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed" error

Tags: powershell, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a string in Powershell and am getting this error. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception can represent a lot of different things, and not all of them are related to the padding, so I have tried to catalogue all the different scenarios where this can occur.

If you know of another situation where this padding exception is thrown, please add it.

To start, this is an example of encryption/decryption that works as expected.

```
$testData = "Hi there! This is a test of a string during encryption"
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$data = $enc.getBytes($testData)

# Encrypt some data

$encryptAlgorithm = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm] (New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider)

$encryptAlgorithm.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
$encryptAlgorithm.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
$encryptAlgorithm.KeySize = 128
$encryptAlgorithm.BlockSize = 128
$encryptAlgorithm.Key = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
$encryptAlgorithm.IV = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)


$encryptor = [System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform]$encryptAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor()
$encryptorMemoryStream = new-Object IO.MemoryStream
$encryptorCryptoStream = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $encryptorMemoryStream,$encryptor,"Write"
$encryptorCryptoStream.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
$encryptorCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

$encryptedData = $encryptorMemoryStream.ToArray()

Write-Host $enc.GetString($encryptedData)
Write-Host $encryptedData.Length

# Decrypt some data
$descryptAlgorithm = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm] (New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider)

$descryptAlgorithm.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
$descryptAlgorithm.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::PKCS7
$descryptAlgorithm.KeySize = 128
$descryptAlgorithm.BlockSize = 128
$descryptAlgorithm.Key = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
$descryptAlgorithm.IV = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)

$decryptor = [System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform]$descryptAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor()

$dataToDecrypt = $encryptedData

$decryptorMemoryStream = new-Object IO.MemoryStream @(,$dataToDecrypt)
$decryptorCryptoStream = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $decryptorMemoryStream,$decryptor,"Read"
$streamReader = new-Object IO.StreamReader $decryptorCryptoStream
try
{
    Write-Output $streamReader.ReadToEnd()
}
catch
{
    $e = $_.Exception
    $msg = $e.Message
    while ($e.InnerException) {
      $e = $e.InnerException
      $msg += "`n" + $e.Message
    }
    $msg
}
```

Let's look at some examples that trigger the padding exception.

**Failing to flush the final block**

This [blog post](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/oh-no-my-paddings-invalid/) has a good write up of this scenario.

```
#$encryptorCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
```

**Invalid keys**

I've changed the byte array used for the decryption key slightly here to simulate keys that don't match.

```
$descryptAlgorithm.Key = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17)
```

**RijndaelManaged with an empty input**

```
$descryptAlgorithm = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm] (New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged)
// ...
$dataToDecrypt = @()
```

**Invalid padding**

I've manually added some invalid padding to the end of the data to decrypt.

```
$dataToDecrypt = $encryptedData + @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
```

**Different padding schemes**

Interestingly only some padding scheme combinations result in the padding error. A lot will decrypt without error, even if the resulting sting is incorrect.

```
$descryptAlgorithm.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::ANSIX923
```

**Different block sizes**

```
$descryptAlgorithm.BlockSize = 64
```

Comment: Those are the immediate errors, but there are many more: Wrong key, wrong IV (with single block messages), wrong encoding of the ciphertext/IV/key. It is important to note that the padding check should not be used as an indicator that something was wrong, because roughly 1 in 256 ciphertext will be decryptable without correct inputs. That is why it is important to use either an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or use an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: Also not mentioned: 1. For debugging decrypt with no padding, that way you an see the padding and tell it is really a padding error (generally not) or another error. 2. If the IV is incorrect only the first block will be wrong so this can be verified. 3. If the encryption is AES, the general case, the block size will be 128-bits. While Rijndael with a non-AES block size or key size is possible that is rare. 4. If the finalize call is not made the output size will be incorrect.

Comment: All in all this is not a a particularly through or helpful question-answer pair. Also shouldn't the code be in the question? The question should be deleted as too broad, and unclear what is being asked, and why isn't this code working (if there was any code).

Comment: The IV should be random bytes, generally prefixed to the encrypted data for use in decryption—never the same as the key. Padding error indications should never be returned to the caller, to do so can result in a padding oracle security flaw.